# remove last line(s) if they are empty from a bunch of files

Tags: php, terminal

Some hosting provider I work with is very strict, if the last line(s) of a php file are empty it throws a fatal error and the site is broken.

The problem is that I've got a lot of php files where the last line might be empty and now I am looking for a way to automatically remove those lines...

I've tried to use sed:

```
sed -i '${/^$/d}' bla.php
```

but all i get is an error

```
sed: 1: "bla.php": extra characters at the end of d command
```

btw: i am using iTerm on the Mac

Comment: Why would a provider not allow the last line in a php file to be empty?

Comment: What kind of fatal error?

Comment: It probably has something to do with session and/or headers.

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of these files with a blank last line..? Is the blank line _after_ the closing php tag per chance?

Comment: @Stuart: yes the blank lines are after the closing tag

Comment: What happens if you omit the closing tag?

Comment: @AbraCadaver it's a wordpress page. within wp-settings.php a lot of files get included via require() and require_once(). if only one of those files has a blank line as last line the execution stops.

e.g. PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Taxonomy' not found in /wordpress/wp-includes/taxonomy.php 

if i fix the last line in taxonomy.php it moans the about the next php file...and so on....and so on.

Comment: @Stuart there is no closing tag, the php files start with <?php and end with the closing bracket of the last function (plus the optional empty line)

Comment: Oh i see, so the blank line os not after the closing tag after all, as there is no closing tag... It makes no sense that an error would occur for simply a blank line after a closing brace though.

Comment: @simon i've asked the hosting provider and they said it is a "general security measurement of php: when a line cannot be executed properly it throws an error. an empty line cannot be executed thus the error is thrown." however: i've uploaded the same code to another (better) hosting provider (where i even have ssh access which i won't get at this shitty place) and it worked just fine, same locally on my machine. so the hosting provider is pretty lame but it's the one i have to use.

Comment: So is it a PHP error or a webserver error? What's the error message?

Comment: You can create a Php script that reads the contents of each Php file and converts it to an array using explode function. Your script can then remove the last line from this array and then convert it back to a string using implode function. The resulting string can be saved back to the Php file

Comment: @nerdess your hosting provider is dodgy. Move to a better one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this within your loop.

```
file_put_contents('[target_file]', implode('', file('[file_being_processed]', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)));
```

The `target_file` would be your new copy of the file you're processing and the `file_being_processed` is self explanatory. You would need to add more logic into the loop to keep the same names.

Bare in mind the above code will exclude all blank lines no matter where they are, so you will also need to add some logic to only apply the above code to the last line of the file.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried turning off `error_reporting`?

Insert the following on the first line of your php files

```
<?php error_reporting(0); ?>
```

Comment: Turning off error reporting is **never** the solution to a problem.